# Multiple toggled boxes opening instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some sources(information, links, etc) I'd like to be hidden, although unfinished it works as expected, only issue I'm currently having is that multiple boxes are opening instead of just the box I clicked to toggle. (I've ran into this issue before and fixed it easily, but it was straight up javascript, whereas right now I'm using PHP to output dynamic data).

I created a custom html `footnote-id` tag, as an unique identifier for the button clicks, but I'm not sure how to attach that to the targeted click.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dxn8eLb/2/).

```js
var button = $(".footnote-button");
var container = $(button.next());
var content = $(button.next().find(".footnote-content-data"));
var readmore = $(button.next().find(".footnote-readmore"));

button.on('click', function(e){
  container.fadeToggle();
});

// Hide container if clicked outside container
$(document).mouseup(function(event){
    if(!container.is(event.target) && !button.is(event.target)  && !content.is(event.target) && container.is(":visible")){
       container.fadeToggle();
    } else{
      return false;
    }
});

// Check if container scrollbar has reached the bottom
$(content).on('scroll', function(){
 if(content[0].scrollHeight - content.scrollTop() - content[0].clientHeight < 1){
   readmore.fadeOut();
  } else {
   readmore.fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans'
}

.footnote {
  position: relative;
}

.footnote-button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0.3em 0 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

.footnote-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 120;
  width: 22em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  background: #fafafa;
  left: -77px;
  top: 45px;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.footnote-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -0.65em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 87px;
}

.footnote-content {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footnote-content-data {
  color: #797979;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 310px;
  margin-right: -50px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.footnote-content::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 50%, rgba(250, 250, 250, 0) 100%);
  height: 1.1em;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.footnote-content::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fafafa 50%, rgba(250, 250, 250, 0) 100%);
  height: 1.1em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.footnote-readmore {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.3375em;
  left: 0.3375em;
  z-index: 14;
  display: block;
  height: 0.78125em;
  width: 0.625em;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex;">
  <p>Some paragraph so it's not empty.</p>
  <div class="footnote">
    <span class="footnote-button" footenote-id="1">1</span>
    <div class="footnote-container">
      <div class="footnote-arrow"></div>
      <div class="footnote-content">
      <span class="footnote-readmore"></span>
        <div class="footnote-content-data">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum nunc nunc, a pulvinar eros semper id. Donec et mauris tellus. Nulla facilisi. Sed eu pellentesque nisl, ut placerat orci. Etiam tempus metus ex, eu vulputate urna tincidunt quis.
          Donec commodo, ligula id pretium ultricies, nisl ex congue risus, ut tempor leo nisl nec neque. Pellentesque porta vehicula lacus, vitae scelerisque ligula. Sed in lacus a nisl sodales lacinia. Aenean consectetur placerat libero nec varius.
          Sed ut leo condimentum, condimentum odio a, tincidunt lorem. Ut ut blandit ex. Aenean libero felis, tincidunt nec tristique a, fermentum quis dui. Cras in eros euismod, sollicitudin dolor in, tempus massa. Ut sollicitudin lorem ut erat tempus,
          sed varius nisl commodo. Fusce in feugiat dui, non sagittis tellus. Donec urna dolor, consequat eget facilisis id, ultrices vitae sapien. Nullam at fringilla nisi. Nulla sagittis egestas urna vel viverra. Nulla eu nunc a elit pretium dignissim.
          Mauris eget cursus nisl. Integer congue malesuada condimentum. Nunc volutpat ligula et placerat malesuada. Cras hendrerit, tortor non viverra imperdiet, erat dolor laoreet nisl, a vestibulum neque lacus sollicitudin justo.
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div style="display: flex;">
  <p>A different paragraph for this second box.</p>
  <div class="footnote">
    <span class="footnote-button" footenote-id="2">2</span>
    <div class="footnote-container">
      <div class="footnote-arrow"></div>
      <div class="footnote-content">
      <span class="footnote-readmore"></span>
        <div class="footnote-content-data">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum nunc nunc, a pulvinar eros semper id. Donec et mauris tellus. Nulla facilisi. Sed eu pellentesque nisl, ut placerat orci. Etiam tempus metus ex, eu vulputate urna tincidunt quis.
          Donec commodo, ligula id pretium ultricies, nisl ex congue risus, ut tempor leo nisl nec neque. Pellentesque porta vehicula lacus, vitae scelerisque ligula. Sed in lacus a nisl sodales lacinia. Aenean consectetur placerat libero nec varius.
          Sed ut leo condimentum, condimentum odio a, tincidunt lorem. Ut ut blandit ex. Aenean libero felis, tincidunt nec tristique a, fermentum quis dui. Cras in eros euismod, sollicitudin dolor in, tempus massa. Ut sollicitudin lorem ut erat tempus,
          sed varius nisl commodo. Fusce in feugiat dui, non sagittis tellus. Donec urna dolor, consequat eget facilisis id, ultrices vitae sapien. Nullam at fringilla nisi. Nulla sagittis egestas urna vel viverra. Nulla eu nunc a elit pretium dignissim.
          Mauris eget cursus nisl. Integer congue malesuada condimentum. Nunc volutpat ligula et placerat malesuada. Cras hendrerit, tortor non viverra imperdiet, erat dolor laoreet nisl, a vestibulum neque lacus sollicitudin justo.
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>a
```

Comment: If you console log your container you will see that it has two elements in it.  When you perform `next()` it will get the next element for each element in the result stack of the jQuery object it is executed off of.  That is why it is showing multiple elements.

Comment: Also as a small side note.  The result of `find()` is already a jQuery object, so doing `$(jQueryObject.find(...))` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your clicker handler to the following:

```
button.on('click', function(e){
  $(e.target).next().fadeToggle();
});
```

When you click the button you want to trigger the container that is after it.  Right now your container element contains multiple elements, not just the one after the button you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `button` variable selects multiple elements your handler applies and acts on all of them. To fix your main issue you need to use either one of the following:

```
$(e.target).next().fadeToggle(); // OR
$(e.target).siblings().fadeToggle(); // Other ways are via .parent().children() etc
```

Now on to the second issue:

You attach a handler on `$(document).mouseup(function(event)` which causes when the user attempts to click on the background you open the next tooltip and it is an infinite loop (again due to the container selector being an array).

To address this change your `mouseup` handler to this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(event){
        console.dir(event.target);    
    if(!container.is(event.target) && !button.is(event.target)  && !content.is(event.target) && container.is(":visible")){
         container.each(function(i, el) {
                $el = $(el)
                if($el.is(':visible'))
                    $el.fadeToggle();
             })
    } else{
      return false;
    }
});
```

Unless this is a desired behaviour in which case please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

The global variable container gets the all of the first immediate siblings of the elements with a class of `footnote-button`. You want to get the immediate sibling of the element with a class of `footnote-button` that was clicked on.

Change

```
button.on('click', function(e){
  container.fadeToggle();
});
```

To

```
button.on('click', function(e){
  $(this).next().fadeToggle();
});
```

```js
var button = $(".footnote-button");
var container = $(button.next());
var content = $(button.next().find(".footnote-content-data"));
var readmore = $(button.next().find(".footnote-readmore"));

button.on('click', function(e){
  $(this).next().fadeToggle();
});

// Hide container if clicked outside container
$(document).mouseup(function(event){
    
    if(!container.is(event.target) && !button.is(event.target)  && !content.is(event.target) && container.is(":visible")){
       container.fadeToggle();
    } else{
      return false;
    }
});

// Check if container scrollbar has reached the bottom
$(content).on('scroll', function(){
 if(content[0].scrollHeight - content.scrollTop() - content[0].clientHeight < 1){
   readmore.fadeOut();
  } else {
   readmore.fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans'
}

.footnote {
  position: relative;
}

.footnote-button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0.3em 0 0.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

.footnote-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 120;
  width: 22em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  background: #fafafa;
  left: -77px;
  top: 45px;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.footnote-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -0.65em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 87px;
}

.footnote-content {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footnote-content-data {
  color: #797979;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 310px;
  margin-right: -50px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.footnote-content::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 50%, rgba(250, 250, 250, 0) 100%);
  height: 1.1em;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.footnote-content::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fafafa 50%, rgba(250, 250, 250, 0) 100%);
  height: 1.1em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.footnote-readmore {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.3375em;
  left: 0.3375em;
  z-index: 14;
  display: block;
  height: 0.78125em;
  width: 0.625em;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTJweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNXB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTIgMTUiIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ieE1pbllNaW4iPgogICAgPGcgc3Ryb2tlPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjEiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0iZXZlbm9kZCI+CiAgICAgICAgPGcgaWQ9IkFycm93IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSgxLjAwMDAwMCwgMS4wMDAwMDApIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjIiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lY2FwPSJzcXVhcmUiPgogICAgICAgICAgICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNNSwwIEw1LDExLjUiIGlkPSJMaW5lIj48L3BhdGg+CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wLjUsNy41IEw1LjAyNzY5Mjc5LDEyLjAyNzY5MjgiIGlkPSJMaW5lIj48L3BhdGg+CiAgICAgICAgICAgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik00LjUsNy41IEw5LjAyNzY5Mjc5LDEyLjAyNzY5MjgiIGlkPSJMaW5lLTIiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDcuMDAwMDAwLCAxMC4wMDAwMDApIHNjYWxlKC0xLCAxKSB0cmFuc2xhdGUoLTcuMDAwMDAwLCAtMTAuMDAwMDAwKSAiPjwvcGF0aD4KICAgICAgICA8L2c+CiAgICA8L2c+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=');
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex;">
  <p>Some paragraph so it's not empty.</p>
  <div class="footnote">
    <span class="footnote-button" footenote-id="1">1</span>
    <div class="footnote-container">
      <div class="footnote-arrow"></div>
      <div class="footnote-content">
      <span class="footnote-readmore"></span>
        <div class="footnote-content-data">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum nunc nunc, a pulvinar eros semper id. Donec et mauris tellus. Nulla facilisi. Sed eu pellentesque nisl, ut placerat orci. Etiam tempus metus ex, eu vulputate urna tincidunt quis.
          Donec commodo, ligula id pretium ultricies, nisl ex congue risus, ut tempor leo nisl nec neque. Pellentesque porta vehicula lacus, vitae scelerisque ligula. Sed in lacus a nisl sodales lacinia. Aenean consectetur placerat libero nec varius.
          Sed ut leo condimentum, condimentum odio a, tincidunt lorem. Ut ut blandit ex. Aenean libero felis, tincidunt nec tristique a, fermentum quis dui. Cras in eros euismod, sollicitudin dolor in, tempus massa. Ut sollicitudin lorem ut erat tempus,
          sed varius nisl commodo. Fusce in feugiat dui, non sagittis tellus. Donec urna dolor, consequat eget facilisis id, ultrices vitae sapien. Nullam at fringilla nisi. Nulla sagittis egestas urna vel viverra. Nulla eu nunc a elit pretium dignissim.
          Mauris eget cursus nisl. Integer congue malesuada condimentum. Nunc volutpat ligula et placerat malesuada. Cras hendrerit, tortor non viverra imperdiet, erat dolor laoreet nisl, a vestibulum neque lacus sollicitudin justo.
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div style="display: flex;">
  <p>A different paragraph for this second box.</p>
  <div class="footnote">
    <span class="footnote-button" footenote-id="2">2</span>
    <div class="footnote-container">
      <div class="footnote-arrow"></div>
      <div class="footnote-content">
      <span class="footnote-readmore"></span>
        <div class="footnote-content-data">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum nunc nunc, a pulvinar eros semper id. Donec et mauris tellus. Nulla facilisi. Sed eu pellentesque nisl, ut placerat orci. Etiam tempus metus ex, eu vulputate urna tincidunt quis.
          Donec commodo, ligula id pretium ultricies, nisl ex congue risus, ut tempor leo nisl nec neque. Pellentesque porta vehicula lacus, vitae scelerisque ligula. Sed in lacus a nisl sodales lacinia. Aenean consectetur placerat libero nec varius.
          Sed ut leo condimentum, condimentum odio a, tincidunt lorem. Ut ut blandit ex. Aenean libero felis, tincidunt nec tristique a, fermentum quis dui. Cras in eros euismod, sollicitudin dolor in, tempus massa. Ut sollicitudin lorem ut erat tempus,
          sed varius nisl commodo. Fusce in feugiat dui, non sagittis tellus. Donec urna dolor, consequat eget facilisis id, ultrices vitae sapien. Nullam at fringilla nisi. Nulla sagittis egestas urna vel viverra. Nulla eu nunc a elit pretium dignissim.
          Mauris eget cursus nisl. Integer congue malesuada condimentum. Nunc volutpat ligula et placerat malesuada. Cras hendrerit, tortor non viverra imperdiet, erat dolor laoreet nisl, a vestibulum neque lacus sollicitudin justo.
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>a
```